# Why does Goland color `err` differently?

Tags: go, goland

I have this code in Go:

```golang
func Provision(env string) error {
    primaryPath, err := FindPrimaryRegionForEnv(env)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    region := extractRegionFromEnvPath(env, primaryPath)
    if err = ProvisionTableInDynamoDB(env, region); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Which Goland colors like this:

[image]

When I change `if err = ...` to `if err := ...` then the color of `err` changes:

[image]

What does the greenish `err` mean?

Comment: I'd guess it's because in the second example, the green `err` var is a different variable which shadows the blue `err` var.

Comment: This is actually not allowed. It will fail to build. I would assume it marks it with red underline. https://go.dev/play/p/8cjNBhFO1ZW

Comment: @TheFool it actually works if you wrap inside an if which creates a new scope, it is related to shadow variable as Adrian mentioned
https://go.dev/play/p/IhCaTLMLMTY

Comment: @TheFool on the second scenario is scoped to `if` condition. That function has the split-brain issue.

Comment: OK right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you get a third color if you nest another scope? Rainbow scopes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to how shadow variables work in pretty much all type-safe languages. In this case, green `err` mean that you're redeclaring the variable rather than changing its value.

The reason why Goland bothered to highlight is this is that within the scope of the redeclaration you may get a value/type that contradicts the shadow declaration.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func boolErrType() bool {
    return false
}

func errType() error {
    return errors.New("this is an error")
}

func main() {
    err := boolErrType()
    if !err {
        fmt.Printf("Within boolErrType if condition: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(err).String())
    }

    if err := errType(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Within errType if condition: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(err).String())
    }

    fmt.Printf("Within main function: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(err).String())
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/IwDb7iBZYc2

In this example you've two different behaviours, the `err` will be a *boolean* type within the `main block`. Except for when it's in the `if` condition scope, it will be given an *error* type.

This is mainly affected when you've started using shadow variables outside of the error scenarios as you could be for example pass an incorrect pointer to a function that causes an unexpected error. Go compiler will have a hard time tracking these shadow variables and won't always catch them at build time.

This could leave unexpected/unknown bugs in your production applications that user's then will be able to exploit.

Here's an article about this that might be useful as well.
https://nidhi-ag.medium.com/variable-shadowing-in-golang-f500e8e58931